# Upgraded to Laravel 5.3 - Route Not Defined Error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

When previewing the app, I get a route not defined error after the Laravel 5.3 upgrade.  It worked in version 5.2.

```
Route [admin.properties.index] not defined. (View: /home/ubuntu/workspace/resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php) (View: /home/ubuntu/workspace/resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php)
```

This code is from app.blade.php:

```
                    <li>{{ link_to_route('admin.properties.index', 'Properties') }}</li>
```

My web.php file looks like this less the extra routes and comments:

```
    <?php

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::auth();

Route::get('/welcome', 'HomeController@index');

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@home');

Route::group(
    [
        'prefix' => 'admin',
        'namespace' => 'admin',
        'middleware' => 'admin'
    ],
    function () {

            Route::resource('properties', 'PropertiesController');

    }
);
```

This is the first part of the Properties Controller for the index view:

```
    namespace App\Http\Controllers\admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Property;
use App\Http\Requests\PropertyRequest;

class PropertiesController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $properties = Property::paginate(15);
        return view('admin.properties.index')->with('properties', $properties);
    }
```

Am I missing a helper function?  Did the syntax change in 5.3 from 5.2 in the above code?  Any help from anyone experienced in Laravel 5.3 would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In Laravel 5.3 few things deprected. Take a look at this [Guide to upgrade 5.2 to 5.3](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#5.2-deprecations)

Answer (score 2):

The syntax didn't change, however, route naming changed between Laravel 5.2 and Laravel 5.3.

This caused a problem for me problem as well. [An issue was raised](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/15119) a while back, but apparently this change is *intentional*.

Long story short, Laravel 5.3 no longer appends a `.` after the *group* prefix when generating the route name.

You can determine the current route name in 5.3 by running `php artisan route:list` and update your references accordingly.

If you want to emulate the 5.2 route naming, you'll need to *tweak* the `as` property for your route group to include the trailing `.`.

For example:

```
Route::group([
    'as' => 'admin.',
    'prefix' => 'admin',
    'namespace' => 'admin',
    'middleware' => 'admin'
], // ...
```

Comment: A HUGE thank you.  I'm so happy this worked.   In the app.blade.php, I just removed the "admin.", and the route:list helped me so much.   :)